# Cryptoauthlib - An anonymous union can only have non-static data members - segmentation fault

Tags: c++, encryption, microchip

I am trying to compile a c++ program with the cryptoauthlib and I get this (An anonymous union can only have non-static data members) error in the atca_iface.h. I think this is a c11 feature, which is not compatible with c++:

All named structs in the unnamed union throw the error. I removed the names of the structs in the following:

```
typedef struct
{

    ATCAIfaceType  iface_type;      // active iface - how to interpret the union below
    ATCADeviceType devtype;         // explicit device type

    union                           // each instance of an iface cfg defines a single type of interface
    {
        struct //ATCAI2C
        {
            uint8_t  slave_address; // 8-bit slave address
            uint8_t  bus;           // logical i2c bus number, 0-based - HAL will map this to a pin pair for SDA SCL
            uint32_t baud;          // typically 400000
        } atcai2c;

        struct //ATCASWI
        {
            uint8_t bus;        // logical SWI bus - HAL will map this to a pin or uart port
        } atcaswi;

        struct //ATCAUART
        {
            int      port;      // logic port number
            uint32_t baud;      // typically 115200
            uint8_t  wordsize;  // usually 8
            uint8_t  parity;    // 0 == even, 1 == odd, 2 == none
            uint8_t  stopbits;  // 0,1,2
        } atcauart;

        struct //ATCAHID
        {
            int      idx;           // HID enumeration index
            uint32_t vid;           // Vendor ID of kit (0x03EB for CK101)
            uint32_t pid;           // Product ID of kit (0x2312 for CK101)
            uint32_t packetsize;    // Size of the USB packet
            uint8_t  guid[16];      // The GUID for this HID device
        } atcahid;

        struct //ATCACUSTOM
        {
            ATCA_STATUS (*halinit)(void *hal, void *cfg);
            ATCA_STATUS (*halpostinit)(void *iface);
            ATCA_STATUS (*halsend)(void *iface, uint8_t *txdata, int txlength);
            ATCA_STATUS (*halreceive)(void *iface, uint8_t* rxdata, uint16_t* rxlength);
            ATCA_STATUS (*halwake)(void *iface);
            ATCA_STATUS (*halidle)(void *iface);
            ATCA_STATUS (*halsleep)(void *iface);
            ATCA_STATUS (*halrelease)(void* hal_data);
        } atcacustom;

    };

    uint16_t wake_delay;    // microseconds of tWHI + tWLO which varies based on chip type
    int      rx_retries;    // the number of retries to attempt for receiving bytes
    void *   cfg_data;      // opaque data used by HAL in device discovery
} ATCAIfaceCfg;
```

I changed these structs to unnamed structs and it compiles, but I unfortunately get a segmentation fault when calling the init function `ATCA_STATUS atinit(ATCAIface ca_iface);`... I do not call this function directly. I call `atcab_init(&cfg_ateccx08a_i2c_default);`

Is there a way to use this without modifying the interface like I did and why do I get the Segmentation fault?

My hardwaresetup is a CM3 with a ATECC608a connected to I2C 1. The interface is up and I can query it. Do I need to modify the default interface to the correct device type and the correct I2C interface? When I do so I get the same segmentation fault.

EDIT:

Example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cryptoauthlib.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    uint8_t random_number;
    atcab_init(&cfg_ateccx08a_i2c_default);
    ATCA_STATUS status = atcab_random(&random_number);

    std::cout << "status: " << (int)status << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT2:

Someone on github told me that I have to use -DATCA_HAL_I2C as C compiler flag. But I now get `undefined reference to hal_i2c_init` errors

EDIT3:

The problem seems to be with the cmake configuration of the cryptoauthlib, because I am crosscompiling on windows for armhf.

Looking into the cmake configurations

EDIT4:

To reproduce the latest errors:

get cryptoauthlib from [here](https://github.com/MicrochipTech/cryptoauthlib/)
get VisualGDB from [here](https://visualgdb.com/?features=linux)
Install VS 2017
Install VisualGDB
Make a new Project with VisualGDB -> CMAKE Project
Download the latest toolchain from [here](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/arm-linux-gnueabihf/)
Use it from within VisualGDB
Add cryptoauthlib as a reference to the project
Add the following CMAKE commands after `project()` in the CMakeLists.txt of the project:

```
unset(WIN32)
unset(APPLE)
set(UNIX)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fms-extensions -std=c11 -DATCA_HAL_I2C=on -DATCAPRINTF=on")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -DATCA_HAL_I2C=on -DATCAPRINTF=on")
```

build.

EDIT5:

Found that I had to do `set(ATCA_HAL_I2C TRUE)` explicitly in my CMAKE project ... as an option it did not work for me, unfortunately.

Now I get a segmentation fault again here:

```
ATCA_STATUS atcab_random(uint8_t *rand_out)
{
    ...
    ATCACommand ca_cmd = _gDevice->mCommands;

    ...
}
```

I opened this as an [issue](https://github.com/MicrochipTech/cryptoauthlib/issues/43) on github.

Comment: Worked on my machine.  But I had to make up a lot of missing pieces.  Could you make sure your example code is complete and compiles (producing the compiler error)?

Comment: I did not change the union to a struct @john, I deleted the names of the structs in the unnamed union.

Comment: @Eljay I added the example code

Comment: Still does not compile as given.  My tweaked version I had to define ATCAIfaceType, ATCADeviceType, and ATCA_STATUS.  I ran into a different error, which I fixed by giving the anonymous union a name (making it no longer anonymous).

Comment: But then the default interface definitions don't work.. because the compiler can't find the members of the union. I am using gcc 7.3.1... Someone on github told me that I have to use -DATCA_HAL_I2C as C compiler flag. But I now get `undefined reference to hal_i2c_init` errors

Comment: I gave it a type name, not a member name.

Comment: This might be a misunderstanding so: unnamed union with named structs does not work, named union with named structs does work compilerwise, but then the default configurations in `atca_cfgs.c` don't work anymore. unnamed union and unnamed structs work... member names never changed.... I edited the question with updates. I am using unnamed union with unnamed structs.. changed it in the question

Comment: Help us, help you.  Provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that is complete and self-contained.  Try to make it as concise (i.e., minimal) as possible.  Make it so that it is complete, and can be copy-and-pasted, and then compiled, such that it reproduces the problem.  I have not been able to reproduce your problem with the incomplete code provided.

Comment: @Eljay I am sorry... I do not have more code... I am using a custom build gcc 7.3.1 crosscompiler for the raspberry pi 3 on Windows 10 with VisualGDB with the following compile command: C:/SysGCC/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe   -std=c++17 -DATCA_HAL_I2C=on -DATCAPRINTF=on -g   "CMakeFiles/cryptoloader.dir/cryptoloader.cpp.o"   -o cryptoloader -Wl,-rpath,C:/Users/User/source/repos/cryptoloader/cryptoloader/cryptoauthlib/lib cryptoauthlib/lib/libcryptoauth.so -ludev -lrt ... I changed the `atca_iface.h` like I showed in the question.

Comment: And I just have the `main` I showed in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error. The Hardware Abstraction Layer could not connect because the default setting of the bus for the i2c bus `.atcai2c.bus` was set to 2 and it needs to be 1 otherwise it won't find the i2c device.

```
ATCAIfaceCfg cfg_ateccx08a_i2c_default = {
    .iface_type             = ATCA_I2C_IFACE,
    .devtype                = ATECC608A,
    .atcai2c.slave_address  = 0xC0,
    .atcai2c.bus            = 1,
    .atcai2c.baud           = 400000,
    //.atcai2c.baud = 100000,
    .wake_delay             = 1500,
    .rx_retries             = 20
};
```

I can now get the revision, the serial and random numbers from the chip with the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cryptoauthlib.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    ATCAIfaceCfg *atca_cfg;
    atca_cfg = &cfg_ateccx08a_i2c_default;

    ATCA_STATUS status = atcab_init(atca_cfg);

    std::cout << "status: " << (int)status << std::endl;

    uint8_t revision[4];
    status = atcab_info(revision);
    if (status != ATCA_SUCCESS)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "revision: " << (int)revision << std::endl;

    uint8_t serial[ATCA_SERIAL_NUM_SIZE];
    status = atcab_read_serial_number(serial);
    if (status != ATCA_SUCCESS)
    {
        return - 1;
    }
    std::cout << "serial: " << (int)serial << std::endl;

    uint8_t num[32];
    status = atcab_random(num);
    if (status != ATCA_SUCCESS)
    {
        return - 1;
    }
    std::cout << "random: " << (int)num << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I will continue this on github.